# Implementing collapsible behavior in a tree graph using GraphView package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently working on implementing a tree graph using the GraphView package (^1.2.0) in my project. However, I'm facing some challenges in making the graph collapsible. Specifically, I would like to achieve an expansion tile-like behavior where, upon clicking a manager node, the users belonging to that particular manager should be displayed. Additionally, if a subtree is already expanded, it should be collapsible.

Here's the relevant code I have implemented so far:

```
 Graph generateGraphTree() {
    Graph graph = Graph()..isTree = true;;

    // Create nodes for each unique role
    Map<String?, Node> roleNodes = {};
    widget.userModelList.forEach((element) {
      Node roleNode = Node.Id(
          Visibility(
            // Admin dont have reporting manager
            visible: (element.roleID == ConstantValue.admin) ? true : widget.collapsedStates![element.reportingManagerId]!,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                if(element.roleID == ConstantValue.manager){
                  print("Before");
                  print(widget.collapsedStates);
                  setState(() {
                    widget.collapsedStates![element.reportingManagerId!] = !(widget.collapsedStates![element.reportingManagerId]!);
                  });
                  print("After");
                  print(widget.collapsedStates);
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: (element.roleID == ConstantValue.admin)
                              ? Colors.indigo.shade900
                              : (element.roleID == ConstantValue.manager)
                              ? Colors.indigo.shade500
                              : Colors.indigo.shade100,
                          spreadRadius: 1),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '${element.name}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: (element.roleID == ConstantValue.user)
                                ? Colors.indigo.shade900
                                : Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 2.0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 1.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          color: (element.roleID == ConstantValue.user) ? Colors.indigo.shade900 : Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "${element.roleID!}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: (element.roleID == ConstantValue.user)
                                ? Colors.indigo.shade900
                                : Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          )
      );
        roleNodes[element.email!] = roleNode;
        graph.nodes.add(roleNode);
    });
    // Connect the nodes based on user roles
    for (UserModel user in widget.userModelList) {
      if(user.reportingManagerId != null && user.reportingManagerId!.isNotEmpty){
          Node? sourceNode = roleNodes[user.reportingManagerId!];
          Node? destinationNode = roleNodes[user.email!];
          if(sourceNode != null && destinationNode != null &&
              ((user.roleID == ConstantValue.admin)? true : widget.collapsedStates![user.reportingManagerId]!)){
            graph.addEdge(sourceNode, destinationNode,
                paint:(user.roleID == ConstantValue.admin) ? (Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.green
                  ..strokeWidth = 1
                  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke) :
                (user.roleID == ConstantValue.manager) ? (Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.indigo.shade900
                  ..strokeWidth = 1
                  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke) : (Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.indigo.shade500
                  ..strokeWidth = 1
                  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke) ,
            );
          }
      }
    }
    builder
      ..siblingSeparation = (100)
      ..levelSeparation = (150)
      ..subtreeSeparation = (150)
      ..orientation = (BuchheimWalkerConfiguration.ORIENTATION_TOP_BOTTOM);
    return graph;
  }

  BuchheimWalkerConfiguration builder = BuchheimWalkerConfiguration();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(child: g.Obx(() {
        return Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              constrained: false,
              boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
              minScale: 0.01,
              maxScale: 5.6,
              child: GraphView(
                graph: generateGraphTree(),
                algorithm: BuchheimWalkerAlgorithm(
                    builder, TreeEdgeRenderer(builder)),
                paint: Paint()
                  ..color = Colors.green
                  ..strokeWidth = 1
                  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
                builder: (Node node) {
                 return node.key!.value;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    })));
  }
```

I have successfully implemented the basic tree graph structure using the GraphView package. However, I'm unsure how to proceed with adding the collapsible behavior to the graph.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to achieve the desired expansion tile-like behavior? Specifically, I need help with toggling the display of users under the manager node upon tapping, as well as implementing the collapsing behavior when a subtree is already expanded.

Any code snippets or suggestions on modifying the existing code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Currently the output of the code is [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGJZv.png)

I Have Wrapped the Node into visibility widget so if the visibility is true node will be display. But its not working.